# react-router v4 async transitions

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

in react router 4.x getComponents as been removed but in the docs I cannot seem to find any means to replace it. We use it quite much in our application as it makes the views quite simple as no cases need to be handled where data is not yet present. In some cases the view is re-used with data from other api calls. Is there any way this can be replaced without putting the initialisation logic into the components?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-v4-transition. Which may help you. In the example I give you could do a component that does the job of getComponent instead of Transition. It should be quite stable, and I use it myself in a project that needed that kind of feature.

Comment: nice, that could help. i will investigate this. thanks